# Determine the base and the dimension of subspace $W$ given as generated space (set of linear combinations) of $3$-vectors in $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, gaussian-elimination

Hello everybody I'm not certain with this question.

> So if lets say
> $$
> W = L\bigl((1,1,0,-1),\, (0,-1,1,1),\, (3,1,2,-1)\bigr) \subset \mathbb{R}^4; 
> $$
> $L$ being the space generated or set of linear combinations of these vectors I want to find the base and the dimension of $W$.

So my thinking is I need to use Gaussian Elimination Matrix and put these $3$ vectors and find the rank which in this case I got $\operatorname{rank} = 2$. So by this the first two columns have pivot and that means that the first two vectors are base for $W$ which means it is a $2$-dimensional matrix.

Is my approach correct? Any feedback is gladly appreciated!

Comment: Yes, since the first two vectors are linearily independent, but all three together are linearily dependent, the space is $2$-dimensional. You can take the first two vectors as a basis.

Comment: @StiftungWarentest thank you just cleared my doubts.